# Is there a way how can I specify Youtube search command?

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube-data-api

Is there a way how can I improve my script to stop returning me data from the same channel?
For example, I want my code to skip parsing video data from channels that were actually scraped yet and get me only one data result per one channel, not more.

```
youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey = api_key)

print(type(youtube))
pp = PrettyPrinter()
nextPageToken = ''

for x in range(1):
#while True:
    request = youtube.search().list(
        q='I stand with Ukraine',
        part='id,snippet',
        maxResults=5,
        order="viewCount",
        pageToken=nextPageToken,
        type='video')
    
    print(type(request))
    res = request.execute()
    pp.pprint(res) 
    
    if 'nextPageToken' in res:
        nextPageToken = res['nextPageToken']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter `items` to consider channels only once, just keep track of considered channels with a [Python `set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and reconstruct `items` by filtering with this `set`.

To do so add before your loops:

```
channelIds = set()
```

And before the `nextPageToken` management, add:

```
    items = []
    for item in res['items']:
        channelId = item['snippet']['channelId']
        if not channelId in channelIds:
            channelIds.add(channelId)
            items += [item]

    res['items'] = items
```